# Automatically zoom-out on ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica chooses the PlotRange for a ListPlot such that the lowest x-value lies on the y-axis and vice versa. Because of this these points often are difficult to find. I could increase the dot size, but then a listplot easily becomes messy.

Isn't there some kind of zoom-out function or parameter which increases the limits of both plotranges? I tried ImagePadding, but that adds a padding around the full plot, including the axes.

Comment: `PlotRangePadding`?

Comment: @kguler - I almost felt embarrassed that I didn't find that, but it doesn't do the trick: the points remain on the axes. Oddly, in the help file example it does exactly what I want. Thanks for your reply, anyway.

Comment: You can set the x and y ranges both with `PlotRange->{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}`

Comment: @steven, you probably need to play with `AxesOrigin` too.

Comment: Steven, nice to see you posting again. :-)

Comment: Related: [(13021)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13021/121), [(22774)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22774/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose using [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) and a partial [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html) in place of axis lines:

```
ListPlot[Prime @ Range @ 25,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1],
 Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever! Thanks a bunch. (I knew you would be here :-))

Comment: @steven You're welcome.  How are you?

Comment: Fine, thanks. Not very much mathematica for the moment, and active in electronics, but not on stackexchange for the moment. Olin must have taken my #1 position long ago already :-)

Comment: It seems the "Axes->False" isn't required; apparently the Frame parameter switches off axes automagically.

Comment: @stevenvh In version 10 it is required; without it I get:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/aYBHb.png

Comment: Should have added that I'm still on version 9 :-)