# How can "lift" a plot which passes near y=0?

Tags: plotting

I know this plot below does not touch b=0. How can I lift it in order to see those values near b[M]=0? I tried

```
LogLogPlot[b[M],{M,10^9,10^14},PlotRange->All,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]

LogLogPlot[b[M],{M,10^9,10^14},PlotRange->{0,6},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]

LogLogPlot[b[M],{M,10^9,10^14},PlotRange->Automatic]
```

Function `b[M]` comes from a list of data which was iterpolated. But I think that is not a problem.

(It must be plotted in log scale since in order to see some details I want)

[image: Plot]

Comment: `LogLogPlot[b[M]+1,{M,10^9,10^14},PlotRange->All,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]`

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(13021)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13021/121), [(22774)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22774/121), [(73240)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73240/121)

Comment: Looks like `B[M]` goes to `1` not `0` ??  Try `PlotRange -> {.9, Automatic}`

Comment: Yes. The problem was solved by shifting the y-axis as `AxesOrigin->{10^9,-0.2}`.

Comment: Not *quite* a dup because of the log scale.. now can anyone make snese of what a negative origin on a log scale actually does?  `AxesOrigin -> {10^9, .8}` seems about the same as `{10^9,-.2}`...

Comment: @Resanrom would you please tell me if my solution from [(73244)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73244/121) is applicable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In some sense, yes. Actually those problems look more complicated but have the same... "central point". I took the idea for shifting the origin from them. Thanks